# Social media integration

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Just want to check if social media integration is possible for Windows phone 8 application? Right now Facebook, Twitter, Mail, SMS integration is possible.

But, Is the following social based application integration is possible?

1. Whatsapp - It has been said not possible. But wanted to check if any latest updates?
2. Wechat
3. hike
4. FB Messenger

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible due to API restrictions. Facebook chat was included once, but Facebook Messenger replace that functionality.